# Email pipe to script works, but still returns bounceback mail

Tags: php, email, pipe

Here's my PHP script that I use for the intercept:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
//Listen to incoming e-mails
$sock = fopen("php://stdin", 'r');
$email = '';

//Read e-mail into buffer
while (!feof($sock))
{
    $email .= fread($sock, 1024);
}

//Close socket
fclose($sock);

emailPoster('email@address.com', "message");

function emailPoster( $to, $email )
{
    $subject = "Email Intercepted";
    $body = $message;
    $headers    = "To: {$to}\r\n";
    $headers    .= "From: noreply@example.com\r\n";
    $headers    .= "Subject: {$subject}\r\n";
    $headers    .= "Reply-To: noreply@example.com\r\n";
    $headers    .= "Return-Path: noreply@example.com\r\n";
    $headers    .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers    .= "Date: " . date("r") . "\r\n";
    $headers    .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $sender     = '-fnoreply@example.com';
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, $sender) ){
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    } else {
        echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
    }
}
?>
```

and the pipe command I use in cPanel:

`usr/local/bin/php -q /public_html/[mywebsite]/email/intercept.php`

When I send an email to the appropriate address, it does process the intercept.php script, but it also returns a bounceback error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you pipe emails to a php script, you can not use "ECHO" or other output command in your script. every output command make error. Also delete "?>" from end of file. every character after this tag make an output header and cause error.

Comment: Every character after what tag?

Comment: "? >" at the end of file.

Comment: There are no characters after that.

Comment: always remove ? > from the end of piped php file. maybe your text editor can not show some characters such as [tab] [br] or ... also don't use echo command.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the echo statement I write it into a file. Make sure the write permissions in the directory are correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put:

```
return NULL;
```

At the end of your PHP file to stop any return messages which will stop the script from bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

If you call CURL in your script then you need to check the following options:

- `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`: Must be `false` because if `true` it will generate output that bypasses **all** other attempts to stop it.
- `CURLOPT_HEADER`: This may generate issues if set to `true`.  Testing is required for your scenario.

CURL Options documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

The code for setting the CURL options are:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

This is in addition to the following items:

- Start script with `#!/usr/bin/php -q`
- Disable all debug output with: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE);`
- Remove `?>` at the bottom of the script to ensure there is no accidental output.
- End the script with `Return NULL;` to ensure there is nothing returned.

Top of script

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE);
// The rest of your script follows...
```

End of script

```
return null;
```